# Calculate Duration of Two time

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I am new to my sql I am trying to compute the duaration of two time

ex:
timestart = 21:00
timeend = 03:00
result will be 06:00

my query is like this for compute but it gives me result of 18:00 I will really appreciate any help or addvice thank you

```
 TIME_FORMAT(ABS(SEC_TO_TIME(ABS(TIME_TO_SEC(timestart)-TIME_TO_SEC(timeend)))), '%H:%i')
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to both SO and MySQL. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `case`:

```
time_format(sec_to_time(case when timestart < timeend
                             then time_to_sec(timeend) - time_to_sec(timestart) 
                             else 24*60*60 + time_to_sec(timeend) - time_to_sec(timestart)
                        end), '%H:%i'
           )
```